# how to configure Titan with multi Data Center deployment?

Tags: java, cassandra, titan

I am trying use titan version 1.0.0 with a multi Data center deployment,
I am using Cassandra 2.1.9 as my backend.

my deployment topology is:
C* is setup (4 nodes, divided into 2 DC, each contains 2 RACK)

> The current setting is: [?????@????? apps]$ 
>   /apps/cassandra/bin/nodetool status
>
> Datacenter: DC2
>   =============== Status=Up/Down |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
>   --  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack UN  ???.???.125.92  58.51 KB   256     ?
>   d483a0b3-45f7-4a8f-a269-fca19eab08bd  RAC2 UN  ???.???.125.91  76.41
>   KB   256     ?       b31751cd-03a1-489d-8482-c4d0f66b780f  RAC1
>
> Datacenter: DC1
>   =============== Status=Up/Down |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
>   --  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack UN  ???.???.125.89  101.89 KB  256     ?
>   628e72c6-d068-4217-8205-91fe4bf7abf3  RAC1 UN  ???.???.125.90  63.34
>   KB   256     ?       96b9d87b-e5d4-4bdb-9693-5f8f9889a83c  RAC2

I am using a titan client which is part of my java application.
the titan configuration I am using:

> storage.backend=cassandra
>   storage.hostname=???.???.125.89,???.??.125.90
>   storage.port=9160
>   storage.username=cassandra
>   storage.password=cassandra
>   storage.cassandra.read-consistency-level=LOCAL_QUORUM
>   storage.cassandra.write-consistency-level=LOCAL_QUORUM
>   storage.cassandra.replication-strategy-class=org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy
>   storage.cassandra.replication-strategy-options=DC1,2,DC2,2
>   cache.db-cache=false
>   cache.db-cache-clean-wait=20
>   cache.db-cache-time=180000
>   cache.db-cache-size=0.5

what happens when I start my application is I fail when I try to create indexes,
now the application flow is correct because when I work with a single Cassandra node the aplication works fine.

> the error i get in the aplication when i run with multi dc is:
>   2016-03-10T16:46:15.473Z|||main||ASDC-BE||ERROR|||localhost||c.t.t.g.database.StandardTitanGraph|||ActivityType=,
>   Desc=
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.locking.TemporaryLockingException:
>   Temporary locking failure     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.locking.AbstractLocker.writeLock(AbstractLocker.java:295)
>   ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingStore.acquireLock(ExpectedValueCheckingStore.java:89)
>   ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.KCVSProxy.acquireLock(KCVSProxy.java:40)
>   ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.acquireIndexLock(BackendTransaction.java:240)
>   ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.prepareCommit(StandardTitanGraph.java:554)
>   ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.commit(StandardTitanGraph.java:683)
>   ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.commit(StandardTitanTx.java:1352)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.commit(ManagementSystem.java:221)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.att.tlv.sdc.be.dao.titan.TitanGraphClient.createVertexIndixes(TitanGraphClient.java:322)
>   [catalog-dao-1604.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]    at
>   com.att.tlv.sdc.be.dao.titan.TitanGraphClient.createIndexesAndDefaults(TitanGraphClient.java:276)
>   [catalog-dao-1604.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]    at
>   com.att.tlv.sdc.be.dao.titan.TitanGraphClient.createGraph(TitanGraphClient.java:244)
>   [catalog-dao-1604.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]    at
>   com.att.tlv.sdc.be.dao.titan.TitanGraphClient.createGraph(TitanGraphClient.java:225)
>   [catalog-dao-1604.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]    at
>   com.att.tlv.sdc.be.dao.titan.TitanGraphClient.createGraph(TitanGraphClient.java:180)
>   [catalog-dao-1604.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]    .....   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
>   [start.jar:9.3.6.v20151106]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
>   [start.jar:9.3.6.v20151106]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
>   [start.jar:9.3.6.v20151106] Caused by:
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Lock
>   write retry count exceeded    at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.writeSingleLock(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:325)
>   ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.writeSingleLock(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:109)
>   ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.locking.AbstractLocker.writeLock(AbstractLocker.java:290)
>   ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]    ... 108 common frames omitted

does anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sadly I found no help here,
so I continued it in the titan forum:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/fJYH1de5wBw